# Putting Elements in MutableList of Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mutablelist

```
fun main() {
    var list1 = mutableListOf<Any>()
    for(i in 0 until 5) {
        list1.set(i,i)
    }
    println(list1)
}
```

Above Code Gives Index 0 out of Bound for Length 0.
What is the Mistake. How do i put elemnts in the MutableList using Index.

Comment: You are trying to `set` the value of an index, but that operation would require the index to exist, which it doesn't. Either make sure the slots exist before the loop or simply add the values.

Comment: val list = MutableList(5) { it }

Comment: `set` is for replacing an element in a list and its element must exist , if you want to "Put" an element use `add` instead

Comment: IME, creating a collection and _then_ populating it is a very Java approach; in Kotlin, you can more often create it pre-populated, either by calling `map()` or `filter()` or another transforming function on an existing object, or by initialising it as it's created — as in lukas.j's one-liner above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method here.

According to the documentation of set :"It replaces the element and add new at given index with specified element."

Here you declare an empty mutableList. So trying to replace at a certain index will give you an Array Out Of Bounds exception.

If you want to add a new element you need to use the add method : "It adds the given element to the collection."

So if we use add method it can be write like this :

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var list1 = mutableListOf<Any>()
    for(i in 0 until 5) {
        list1.add(i,i)
    }
    println(list1)
}
```

Or without using index parameter :

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var list1 = mutableListOf<Any>()
    for(i in 0 until 5) {
        list1.add(i)
    }
    println(list1)
}
```

You can still use the set method (even if it's not the best way) by declaring the initial length of your mutable list like @lukas.j said:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var list1 = MutableList<Any>(5) {it}
    for(i in 0 until 5) {
        list1.set(i,i)
    }
    println(list1)
}
```